# Create 1 million rows of sample data

Tags: php, mysql

I've been scratching my head for hours now. I need to create 1 million rows of sample data. The table has 3 columns of type integer that need to be within a certain range, so I'm using the rand function to generate random values for each row.

I have all of this in a while loop.

It's taking forever and crashes my local server most of the time without going over 10k rows.

I've tried MySQL COMMIT, increase the php timeout limit and played with MySQL settings, to no avail.

What is the standard way of doing this?

Cheers

Comment: Can you post some code? It sounds like you're doing the right things, but it's hard to verify from just your description.

Comment: Seems like I found a solution (not a very nice one): I simply didn't query the database through the loop but rather built the query and wrote it to a .txt file and then imported that file through phpmyadmin. Takes nearly no time. Why it would take hours the other way, I have no idea.

Comment: You can run a php script from the command line right? If you it that way, would timeout become a non-issue?

Comment: Make sure not to create a new connection with each query. We need more info on how you're doing this: post code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide code that you are using...

**MOST important**, I also need table structure. I am asking for table structure as you might have defined variable as `SMALLINT` (whose range is `–32768 to 32767` in `MYSQL`) and trying to insert higher number...